# How do I check if a UDP port is being in use?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron, udp

How do I check if a UDP port is being in use?

This is for an Angular/Node.js/Electron desktop application.

In C# .NET I've used the API:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetActiveUdpListeners()
```

, then checked if my UDP port was in the array... But I cannot find the syntax for Node.js and JavaScript. Can anyone help me?

If there is no such API for Node.js, are there any workarounds? I feel like I'm unsure what I should be searching.

Thanks.